# MySQL - Grouping with Max & Min Length

Tags: mysql, max, min

I'm not even sure if this is possible, I've tried lots of solutions, but can only ever get a part solution.

I have a table with fields:
uniqueID, pupilID, comment, submitter.

I can easily pull out all of the comments written, ordered by length, but what I want to be able to do is show

Submitter | MIN LENGTH COMMENT | MAX LENGTH COMMENT

If I group on submitter, I can get the minimum, but there doesn't seem to be a way to also include the max length comment they've written.

Any help would be gratefully received.

---

```
SELECT t1.submitter, CONCAT(LEFT(t1.comment,20),'...') AS comment, 
length(comment) as `length`
FROM wwlformtutorcomments t1
LEFT JOIN users u on u.pupilID=t1.pupilID

WHERE t1.commentSubmitDate = (SELECT MAX(t2.commentSubmitDate)
             FROM wwlformtutorcomments t2
             WHERE t2.pupilID = t1.pupilID)

ORDER BY `length`
```

Comment: I think I've solved this using the min() and max () functions...

Comment: if one submitter have several  MIN or MAX  LENGTH COMMENT with same size, do you want output them all ?

Comment: min(length(comment)) as `min length`, max(length(comment)) as `min length`

Comment: @OtoShavadze - no, just the min and max values of the field length :-) - Which I think is why the min (), max() functions as above work for this case. Cheers for the reply though :-)

Comment: can you plz provide some sample data how it looks like